# ASP.NET MVC 4 on IIS 7.5, returns 404. Something to do with extensionless route mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have deployed an MVC 4 web-site to a Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5. .NET 4.5 is installed on the server.

The site works fine locally. All routing works fine. However, when I put it on the server, nothing works. I have confirmed that the DNS/binding is working by putting a static text file in the site and this works.

Here's a few things I've tried:

- The default route / returns 403.13 - indicating directory browsing is disabled (correct). This should surely map to /home/index?
- Any route (eg. /Organisation, Organisation/Index) simply returns 404.
- Made sure all my DLLs are copied over (as per http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)

I have tried/confirmed:

- HttpRedirection is installed on IIS7 (as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023146)
- HttpErrors is installed on IIS7
- All my DLLs are in place

Am I missing something? My next act of desperation is to install the full ASP.NET MVC 4 stack including Visual Studio Express, SQL Express, etc. just to see if it works. Which I really don't want to do. This is a production server!

*Update:*
I should add that the same site works on en equivalent configuration in-house, on a staging server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this same issue. There's a hotfix you should try:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368 
It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Wow. How did you find that. Thanks, sorted!

Comment: I found your post and this hotfix while searching this very issue. Figured I'd share my answer, since I tried all the same things you did, and this was very frustrating.

Comment: it's worth noting this hotfix is rolled into SP1 for Server 2008 R2.  Also, if after applying that hotfix, other things might start to break (i.e. a custom module that does extensionless routing)..  If so, look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2522807

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495346/asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-not-working-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7

Comment: That hotfix no longer seems to be available. Does anyone know where I can get it?

Comment: We have had that error on a single developer machine and searched that damn problem for about 8 hours! Then the hotfix fixed the problem within seconds :) Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this hot fix is rolled up in server 2008 r2 sp1.