# Setting up a simple website with IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and serve it with IIS 7.5. So, I build it in Visual Studio, and then publish the code to a directory. In IIS Manager, I create a new website, whose physical path is the publish directory. The bindings are http:*:80:.

However, when I try to reach the website by typing in the name of my machine on a browser, I get the following error message:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have a default html file?

Comment: No. The content of the publish folder is 5 folders and 4 files. The folders are: bin, Content, Images, Scripts and Views. The files are: favicon.ico, Global.asax, packages.config and Web.config

Comment: Do you have a Home controller with an `Index()` action?

Comment: Are you setting up the website on your local machine or on a web server?

Answer (score 0):

Karnivaurs

Try to use "localhost" or the loop back ip "127.0.0.1" to get to the site.

For the browsing, If its available in IIS then you have to enable it. See [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/directorybrowse)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have the same issue that happened with this question, it solved my problem with IIS on Windows 8

[MVC 4 website with .NET 4.5 on IIS 8 in Windows 8 gives 403.14 forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025455/mvc-4-website-with-net-4-5-on-iis-8-in-windows-8-gives-403-14-forbidden-error)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you run it straight from visual studio? Do you have home/index? To enable directory browsing in IIS , you need to double click on Directory Browsing and Enable it. That way you can see the content of the directory. After that, you can browse to your html page.
[image]