# The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. IIS 8.5 MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, iis-8.5

When I configure IIS and tries to run the mvc application it gets the **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory** error form IIS. I have tried solutions provided by [sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5), [sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden) and [sol3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025455/mvc-4-website-with-net-4-5-on-iis-8-in-windows-8-gives-403-14-forbidden-error) but I am still getting the error. I have Windows 8.1 and when I tried it on Windows 10 it works perfectly. So it must be an environment problem.

Comment: Is ASP.NET [registered with IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) on your Windows 8.1 machine?

Comment: When I try to run aspnet_regiis it returns "This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool". In windows features I have installed .NET 4.5 for IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio 2015 it does not include the MVC4 framework. So I needed to install ASP.NET MVC 4 separately although I have already installed VS 2015 in my machine.