# You do not have permission to view this directory or page (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, windows-authentication

When I published ASP.NET MVC4 site I see error:
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

In Web.Config I use windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

On my local machine everything works perfect. Problem when I published site to server.
I tried to upload another site to this server, everything works. Problem with my site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4 not working on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495346/asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-not-working-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7)

Comment: yes, I'm using Window Server 2008 IIS7.  And it means on this server ASP.NET MVC4 not working?

Answer (score 1):

The error could be that permissions on the folder are not setup.

Need to add local machine `Users` allowing `Read, ReadAndExecute, ListDirectory` permissions.