# How to deploy an ASP NET MVC 4 Web Application using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, windows-server-2008-r2

Firstly, I am sorry for repeat a question but its solution:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495346/asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-not-working-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7/16577694#16577694)

It doesn't work for me. I read the articles in this solution but I can't deploy my ASP NET MVC 4 web application.  I tried this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

and I tried this too:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I downloaded an update:

> An update is available that enables certain IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers
>   to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period

[Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368/es)

[image]

but When I tried to install then

[image]

I am working on:

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

-Internet Information Services 7.5

-Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (Publish using Web Deploy)

-.Net Framework 4.5

[image: My Application Pools]

My Modules

[image]

and finally my web.config (without the module tag because I was using both of them and I got the same result)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /> 
  <handlers> 
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
         <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I publish my web application this is the result:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't deploy my MVC Web Application using one click Publish web deploy, but I deployed my Web Application using the configuration below:

[image]

I didn't need to use this tags:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

or

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```