# Failed to load resource: 403 forbidden with .js Optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, minify

I'm trying to minify my .js and .css files.

I've installed the packed `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`

When ever i active the Optimization with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

**I receive this error on the client:**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) `http://localhost:22773/Content/themes/elevation/v=gnDLBbf1VVRuQDXtIYn1q0P3ICZG7oiwwgxPRbaLvqI1`

Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

---BundleConfig info-------------------------------

```
 public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myJquery").Include(

           "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js",
            "~/Scripts/signalr-hubs.js",
            "~/Scripts/Controls/Select/Simple/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"
        ));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/shared").Include(
            "~/Scripts/global/prototypes.js",
            "~/Scripts/global/mathutil.js",
            "~/Scripts/global/elevationevents.js"
            ));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/core").Include(
            "~/Scripts/elevation/core/sys.config.js",
            "~/Scripts/elevation/core/bays.js",
            "~/Scripts/elevation/core/door.js",
            "~/Scripts/elevation/core/horiziontal.js",
            "~/Scripts/elevation/core/vertical.js"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/elevation").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/dialogs/dialogs.css",
            "~/Content/themes/social/ac/acSocial.css",
            "~/Content/themes/elevation/elevation.css"
      ));
    }
}
```

-----------------------------I still have not got this figured out---------------------

I'm using 2013 .net and iis8 on a windows7 OS

Here is my latest error, I cannot take my solution out of debug mode, because if I do I get that error below.

```
    HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:1499/Content/themes/elevation/?v=aukmuLTC3g_fDko3eWmzqq7A8miRqgsJKXA2GO3w-pg1
Physical Path      c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\AlumCloud\AlumCloud\Content\themes\elevation\
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ALUMCLOUD(3)

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
View more information »
```

---

**Here is the url that is created by iis8 when not in debug mode that produces the error**

```
http://localhost:1499/Content/themes/elevation/?v=aukmuLTC3g_fDko3eWmzqq7A8miRqgsJKXA2GO3w-pg1
```

**Here is the url that returns the actual .css file with out any error**

```
http://localhost:1499/Content/themes/elevation/elevation.css
```

Comment: Are you using any authentication on your website?

Comment: Yes, and I'm currently logged in.

Comment: assuming your _content_ folder only contains styles/images/js scripts, try placing a `web.config` file inside _content_ folder with `<system.web> <authorization> <allow users ="*" /> </authorization> </system.web>` inside it.

Comment: please also provide the `Bundle` include code inside your `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method.

Comment: I've added the web.config file and I'm still getting that 403 Forbidden

Comment: Include all the Bundle related code from `Application_start` method in your question.

Comment: @th1rdey3 , I've included the BundleConfig file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just had the same issue. In my case, the solution was to give the Content bundle a different name. I think that happen because IIS intercepts the requests and treat the bundle name as a directory and since the Content folder really exists, it returns the forbidden error. So, you could rename `~/Content/themes/elevation` to say `~/css/themes/elevation`

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/themes/elevation").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/dialogs/dialogs.css",
            "~/Content/themes/social/ac/acSocial.css",
            "~/Content/themes/elevation/elevation.css"
      ));
```

Also, don't forget to adjust your markup/master page to use the revised bundle name, i.e.

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/css/themes/elevation") %>
```

Then add location directives to the web.config to allow access to the bundles:

```
<location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="bundles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May you format the web config? And path is static? css or bundles? or belong the name of code you calling? like: Styles.Render("~/css/themes/elevation") so path is "css" ?

Comment: The path should be the same as in the bundling code. So, if you want to use a different value, change it in StyleBundle (or ScriptBundle in case of a script bundle), then in Styles.Render()/Scripts.Render() and finally put the new name into the web.config. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

you have to keep the bundle name similar to the actual path of the resources. otherwise system cannot find resources when compiled with `debug='false'` or `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`. because system uses the bundle name to generate the link for the resources. so your bundle names should be like this -

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/myJquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js",
    "~/Scripts/signalr-hubs.js",
    "~/Scripts/Controls/Select/Simple/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/global/shared").Include(
    "~/Scripts/global/prototypes.js",
    "~/Scripts/global/mathutil.js",
    "~/Scripts/global/elevationevents.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/elevation/core/core").Include(
    "~/Scripts/elevation/core/sys.config.js",
    "~/Scripts/elevation/core/bays.js",
    "~/Scripts/elevation/core/door.js",
    "~/Scripts/elevation/core/horiziontal.js",
    "~/Scripts/elevation/core/vertical.js"
));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/dialogs/dialog").Include(
    "~/Content/themes/dialogs/dialogs.css"
));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/social/ac/ac").Include(
    "~/Content/themes/social/ac/acSocial.css"
));
```

**Edit**
This will work on IIS 6. However for IIS 7 or 7.5 the solution is something else. I faced the same problem when I deployed an application in IIS 7.5. The solution is to install a hotfix as discussed in [ASP.NET MVC 4 on IIS 7.5, returns 404. Something to do with extensionless route mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410314/asp-net-mvc-4-on-iis-7-5-returns-404-something-to-do-with-extensionless-route) and [ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4 not working on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495346/asp-net-4-5-mvc-4-not-working-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that must be actually /elevation/v=gn... but not /themes/elevation?v=gnDLBbf (with **?**)?

Comment: You're right now that I think about it, that is if the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization did not alter the paths and or Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization is not caching the files somewhere else. All I've done was install the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization and added the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; to my BundleConfig. Anything other than that I've not done. Did I miss a step?

Comment: So, you mean, when you don't use the Optimization (or if you just set EnableOptimization = false), it works well? If it is, that's strange how it even can work without '?' but with '/' instead, as a bundle with 'Content/themes/elevation/v' name is never mentioned in your bundles provided, that's why you get into Content/themes/elevation/v/ directory, which would obviously give you 403.

Comment: Is there a setting somewhere that I should set to fix this? That I've over looked?

Comment: Ok. What do you get if you use this instead http://localhost:22773/Content/themes/elevation?v=gnDLBbf1VVRuQDXtIYn1q0P3ICZG7oiwwgxPRbaLvqI1?

Comment: I receive this HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: Well, that's really weird. You should the provide the project sources somehow... or at least its certain parts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40465/discussion-between-alumcloud-com-and-agat)

Comment: Just to be clear, could you confirm, that you really use /themes/elevation?v= (with `?`, not `/`)?

Comment: yes, the directory structure is correct. I have not tried the recommendation for @th1rdey3.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com Why you are talking of "Directory structure"?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, the bundle name that you assigned is clashing with an actual existing folder.  As an example, consider the following:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/epic").Include(
    "~/Content/Epic/StickyFooter.css"));
```

Will give me the same type of error noted by OP:

```
{myURL}/content/epic/?v=YTZL7Up6r-0uQblkv6unjKN5Nfb3uwtE0bPz9nxbjDc1 Failed to load
```

This is because the virtual path that the optimizer is trying to create (content/epic) happens to be an existing folder path in my site (I have a folder in the root called "content" and it contains a folder called "epic").  If I change my bundle path to the following:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/epic2").Include(
    "~/Content/Epic/StickyFooter.css"));
```

The problem no longer exists because I don't have a folder called "epic2" inside my "content" folder.

Contrary to the accepted answer, I would advise against changing a bundle directory such as "~/Content/a/b/" to "~/css/a/b" because there's another potential problem that will arise if your stylesheets contain relative references to external files.

Consider my AjaxLoadAnimation.css stylesheet which contains this snippet:

```
...
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5 ) url('images/spin.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
...
```

In order to make sure the reference works for optimized and non-optimized compilation, make sure that the path for the bundle matches the path for each item in the bundle.  If your stylesheets are at ~/Content/my/path, your bundle should start with ~/Content/my/path as well.  To avoid OP's issue, just make sure the name ("sharedcss" in my case) doesn't clash with an existing folder.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/my/path/sharedcss").Include(
    "~/Content/my/path/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/my/path/font-awesome.css",
    "~/Content/my/path/AjaxLoadAnimation.css"));
```

Hopefully this saves other people from the same frustration.