# Server respond with a status 403 (forbidden)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

I'm using `asp.net MVC`. I have hosted my website on `appharbor`. Everything is working fine on localhost. On live website I'm getting error.

> Server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

[image]

To solve this issue. I added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in web.config but it didn't work.

Another solution is I need to You need to change permissions on the folder bootstrap/css. To change permission I have to type command `sudo chmod 0777`. But I cannot figure out where to type this command.

So where I have to type this command or what is the alternative to tackle this `403` issue.

Comment: I know that sudo and chmod are linux commands. You probably need to modify some settings in IIS instrad to allow anonymous acces to that file's directory.

Comment: which settings I have to change in IIS?

Comment: I don't know, it is just a hunch and I dont have an IIS server available right now. If I knew I would have put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I had the same problem now with jstree.

I don't know if you realized, but this behavior is given to you by the [EnableOptimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Basead on Denis Ivin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369898/2088134), you probably have a jstree folder inside Content/plugins and IIS, instead of giving you the jstree.css, is trying to list the folder and that is, by default, forbidden.

In my case I had to do the following for the plugin work as intended:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(
            "~/Content/plugins/jstree/jstree")
            .Include("~/Content/plugins/jstree/style.css"));
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@section css{
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/jstree/jstree")
}
```